# Как перебрать пронумерованные переменные с помощью цикла?

Tags: python, циклы, переменные

Есть переменные data_0, data_1, data_2, data_3 и т.д. Как по очереди обратиться к ним в цикле по типу

```
for i in range(4):
    print(data_i)
```

?

Comment: сделайте из этих переменных список или словарь, будет гораздо меньше головной боли. так `print(locals()['data_'+str(i)])`

Comment: "Вы больше не будете использовать динамическое именование переменных. Вы будете использовать списки или словари."

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy "Почему, мистер Андерсон, почему? Во имя чего?" https://habrastorage.org/getpro/habr/upload_files/4db/ed2/26a/4dbed226a942713b2ef085ad44652c13.png

Answer (score -1):

```python
data_0 = 213
data_1 = 1234
data_2 = 'asdf'

for i in range(3):
    print(eval('data_{}'.format(i)))
```

###### Вывод:

```
213
1234
asdf
```

Comment: Я буду брать по 1000 рублей с каждого, кто рекомендует `eval` там где он не нужен. Во-первых, есть `locals()` и  `globals()`. Во-вторых, работа с динамическими именами переменных никогда не бывает необходима и оправдана. Нужны динамические имена? Используй словарь. Не надо мусорить в пространстве имён.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy `eval()` штука страшная, не спорю, но в данном случае его использование достаточно безопасно и более наглядно. Не эффективно — да. Впрочем зависит от количества переменных в `globals()` и `locals()`, прохождение по ним это дополнительный цикл.

Comment: `eval('data_1')` быстрее `locals()['data_1']`? Когда это началось? Почему мне не сказали? Запустить интерпретатор чтобы обратится к словарю теперь быстрее чем обратится к словарю?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy перечитайте, пожалуйста, предыдущий комментарий. В первых двух предложениях я утверждаю, что `eval()` не эффективен, то есть не быстрее.